# How to round up and down numbers in Java

Tags: java

Im trying to make my program evaluate a expression from left to right ignoring order of operations.

E.g. 5/3+2*3 = 12

Division should round up/down to the nearest integer. **In this example, 5/3 should equate to 2 since 5/3 = 1.666 which rounds up to 2.**

I have made a function which does computes the expression and it works perfectly up until the point the expression involves division. It doesn't round the number properly.
This is how it computes the divion in my code:

```
            if (runningTotal % numbers.get(i + 1) >= 5) {
                runningTotal = (int) Math.ceil(runningTotal / numbers.get(i + 1));
            } else {
                runningTotal = (int) Math.floor(runningTotal / numbers.get(i + 1));
            }
```

runningTotal is an int and numbers is an arraylist containing integers. Is there something wrong with my casting?

Thanks for helping.

EDIT = Figured it out myself. Forgot all about Math.round()....

Comment: If you read the question, I tell you that it evalutes the expression from left to right instead of normal rules of operation.

Comment: @TarikhChouhan that concept is typically referred to as 'order of operations' or 'operator precedence'.

Answer (score 10):

**Math.round()** rounds to the next higher number (in double form) if the fractional part is >= 5, i.e., 7.5, 7.6...  will become 8.0. **Math.ceil()** rounds to the next higher integer number irrespective of the factional part, i.e., 7.4 will become 8.0. And **Math.floor()** is the opposite of ceil(): rounds to the previous integer irrespective of the fractional part, i.e., 7.8 will become 7.0. 
**Math.rint()** is just like Math.round(), but it returns the value in int form.
So you might wanna do this:

```
int r= Math.round(5.0/3.0)+2*3;
//or
int r=Math.rint(5.0/3.0)+2*3;
//rint() in preferable if 'r' is int
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are doing integer division, which will only produce whole numbers. By the time the ceil or floor methods are called, the result is already truncated. Try casting the ints to floats.

`Math.ceil((float)runningTotal / (float)numbers.get(i + 1))`